# php4 - Should i use global variables in this case?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    global $words;

    class A {

        function say()
        {
            global $words;
            $words = 'man';
            A::hello();
            A::bye();

            echo $words;
        }

        function hello(){
            global $words;
            $words .= 'hello';
        }

        function bye(){
            global $words;
            $words .= 'bye';
        }

    }
    A::say();
?>
```

i think it is stupid, Can you pointed me a good way ?

Comment: you shouldn't be using a no longer supported version of php, its dangerous. from the manual "Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued since 2007-12-31. Please consider upgrading to PHP 5."

Comment: @Dagon: i know , but i have to care on php4 :D

Comment: i try to write a script that can run with php4 & 5 :D

Comment: what's the value of supporting php4? may as well support php3.

Comment: On the beautiful day, someone mail for me : hey , your script don't work. my host use php4 :-w  :D

Comment: its good that it does not support php4 nothing written in the last years should, php4 is simply unsafe to use, you do your clients a favour by getting them to upgrade.

Comment: yes, i think like you, but no with my boss :D

Comment: @Chameron , then change the boss.

Comment: @Chameron: teresko is (a kind of) right: If your boss doesn't know, what he is talking about, its also your job to tell him, that he is wrong (maybe in other words ;)). When something gets terrible wrong, because you use an outdated environment, its probably up to you to fix it (and with "terrible" I mean "terrible").

Answer (score 2):

Declare `$words` as a static variable within the class:

```
class A {
    static $words;

    static function say() {
        self::$words = 'man';
        A::hello();
        A::bye();

        echo self::$words;
    }

    static function hello() {
        self::$words .= 'hello';
    }

    static function bye() {
        self::$words .= 'bye';
    }
}

A::say();
```

Comment: Yes. Read more at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php
Note that PHP4 does not support access modifiers. Also, you might need to namespace references from `$words` to `self::$words`. Not sure if PHP makes you do that.

Comment: php4.4.6 : Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}

Answer (score 1):

PHP4 code (compatible with PHP5).

```
class A {

    var $words;

    function A($words) {
        $this->words = $words;
    }

    function say() {
        $this->words = 'man';
        $this->hello();
        $this->bye();
        return $this->words;
    }

    function hello() {
        $this->words .= 'hello';
    }

    function bye() {
        $this->words .= 'bye';
    }
}

$a = new A($words);
echo $a->say();
```

In general, [you do not want to use the `global` keyword when doing OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527). [Pass any dependencies through the ctor or via appropriate setters](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection). Relying on globals will quickly introduce side effects into your application, breaks encapsulation and will make your API lie about it's dependencies. [You should also avoid all static classes](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html) because they will tightly couple the calling class to the static class. This makes maintenance and testing more painful than it needs to be (same for globals).

Also see https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: Thanks, i have change the way i use class